# Calculating CoreData query between rows

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a CoreData Entity - 'columns' of date and distance.

e.g.

```
Date         Dist
---          ---
01/01/2020   20
07/01/2020   70
10/01/2020   60
```

I'd ideally like to pull out all rows (sorted by date) - with each row calculating how many days between this row and the next, then using the next row's distance value, to calculate how much distance has been covered, divided by the number of days.

e.g.

```
Date         Dist Days     Dist   Miles per day
---          ---  ---      ---    ---
01/01/2020   20   7 days   70     10 miles per day
07/01/2020   70   3 days   60     20 miles per day
10/01/2020   60   NA       NA     NA
```

I can't figure out if I should be doing this in the query, or the code - I'm using SwiftUI.

My current code just pulls out all rows through a fetch request, I've no idea where to go from here.

Any help or advice, or if you can point me in the right direction, would be really appreciated.

Comment: Obviously it should be done via the code. First of all, you have to create an extension for your `columns` class. There you can create a needed properties/functions for calculation and show the result in UI. But for `Days` property it is better to add such field to your `columns` entity and count it right away, because in order to get the difference A and B you will have to perform extra calls to CoreData which may reduce the load time.

Answer (score 0):

Do this via code definitely. It might be cleaner to put more data in your entities rather than try recalculate this all on the fly every time. So each entity knows its own start and end date as well as start and end distance.

When you add a new entity just update the previous one with its end values.

Also you could have a routine to go through everything and recalculate it all and save.